# How to fade an image on hover in Wix code?

Tags: javascript, velo

What is the code needed in Wix to make an image fade out of view when the mouse is hovering over the image and fade in view when mouse is not hovering over the image?

I tried using this code (and others similar) but it does not work:

```
export function image4_mouseIn(event) {
  $w.onReady(function () {
   $w('#image4').onMouseIn( (Event) => {
    let fadeOptions = {
        "duration":   500,
        "delay":      500
    };

    $w("#image4").hide("fade", fadeOptions);
  } );
 });
}

export function image4_mouseOut(event) {
 $w.onReady(function () {
  $w('#image4').onMouseOut( (Event) => {
    let fadeOptions = {
        "duration":   500,
        "delay":      500
    };

    $w("#image4").show("fade", fadeOptions);
  } );
 }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

1) You are creating event handlers both dynamically and statically together. You can technically use both methods, but not at the same time.

To do it dynamically (without the regular function declaration):

```
$w.onReady(function () {
  $w('#image4').onMouseIn( (Event) => {
    let fadeOptions = {
      "duration":   500,
      "delay":      500
    };

    $w("#image4").hide("fade", fadeOptions);
  } );
  // show function here 
} );
```

To do it statically (without the onReady)

```
export function image4_mouseIn(event) {
  let fadeOptions = {
    "duration":   500,
    "delay":      500
  };
  $w("#image4").hide("fade", fadeOptions);
}
```

Note: you need to wire this function to the button using the properties panel.

2) You cannot run a mouseOut event on an image that is hidden. To get around this, you can add a box behind the image (the box can be transparent) and create a mouseOut event handler on the box that shows the image again.

```
export function box1_mouseOut(event) {
  let fadeOptions = {
    "duration":   500,
    "delay":      500
  };
  $w("#image4").show("fade", fadeOptions);
}
```

Comment: This code works great! Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right.
On your page code you should have the following:

```
$w.onReady(function () {
   let fadeOptions = {
        "duration":   500,
        "delay":      500
    };      
    $w('#image4').onMouseOut( (Event) => {
      $w('#image4').show('fade', fadeOptions);
    } );
    $w('#image4').onMouseIn( (Event) => {
      $w('#image4').hide('fade', fadeOptions);
    } );
 });
```

Comment: I understand what your doing with this code (looks good logically) but it did not work for me. Thank you so much for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly Working Try this

```
$w.onReady(function () {
   let fadeOptions = {
        "duration":   500,
        "delay":      500
    };      
    $w('#image4').onMouseOut( (Event) => {
      $w('#image4').show('fade', fadeOptions);
    } );
    $w('#image4').onMouseIn( (Event) => {
      $w('#image4').hide('fade', fadeOptions);
    } );
 });
```